# Unix sort command with blank value

Tags: sorting, unix

I am using below sort command to sort 2 fields in desc order and there is a chance that the second field can be blank in some cases.

```
sort -k 1.1,1.2n -brn -k 1.5,1.6 -o
```

sample data:

```
112321 
112422
112526
1124
112623
```

output must be as below

```
1124
112526
112623
112422
112321
```

Can you please help me out with a solution, thanks!!!!

Comment: It is going to be tricky to get a missing field (after `1124`) to compare higher than any of the present fields.

Answer (score 0):

Do it as two separate commands and concatenate the results.

```
{ grep -v '^.....' input | sort -k 1.1,1.2n; 
  grep '^.....' input | sort -k 1.1,1.2n -brn -k 1.5,1.6; } > output
```

Comment: I am actually using the sort command through java using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(UNIXCOMMAND) <br/> Do you this still I can use thee concatenate to merge the result..........

Comment: If it runs the command via the shell, then you should be able to put this entire thing in `UNIXCOMMAND`.

Comment: in the above command where are we actually specifying on which file is to be sorted

Comment: The input file is `input`, the output file is `output`.